# Screen flashing while window is open

Tags: java, tilemap

The screen renders everything in the right place but the entire screen flickers/flashes while it's open. Any Ideas?

TileMapEditor class

```
import com.stardust.main.gfx.Assets;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TileMapEditor
{   
   BufferedImage[] tiles = new BufferedImage[19];

   //array of tile types
   int[][] map = new int[32][32];
   //position coordinates
   public static int posX, posY;

   public TileMapEditor(int posX, int posY) throws IOException
   {
       int x = 0, y = 0;
       this.posX = posX;
       this.posY = posY;
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res/tileMap2.txt"));

       String line;

       while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
       {
           String[] values = line.split(",");

           for(String str : values)
           {
               int str_int = Integer.parseInt(str);
               map[x][y] = str_int;
               System.out.print(map[x][y] + " ");
               y += 1;
           }
           System.out.println("");
           x += 1;
           y = 0;
       }

       in.close();
   }

   public void update()
   {
   }

   public void render(Graphics g)
   {
       for(int x = 0; x < 32; x++)
       {       
           for(int y = 0; y < 32; y++)
           {
               int textureType = map[x][y];
               BufferedImage texture = tiles[textureType]; 
               setTile();
               g.drawImage(texture, posX, posY, null);
               posY += 32;
           }
           posX += 32;
           posY = -Game.HEIGHT / 2;
       }
   }

   public void setTile()
   {
       tiles[0] = Assets.grass;
       tiles[1] = Assets.dirt;
       tiles[2] = Assets.water;
       tiles[3] = Assets.tree;
       tiles[4] = Assets.multiTree;
       tiles[5] = Assets.NSpath;
       tiles[6] = Assets.uprtPath;
       tiles[7] = Assets.EWpath;
       tiles[8] = Assets.upltPath;
       tiles[9] = Assets.dnltPath;
       tiles[10] = Assets.dnrtPath;
       tiles[11] = Assets.watgrsdn;
       tiles[12] = Assets.watgrslt;
       tiles[13] = Assets.watgrsup;
       tiles[14] = Assets.watgrsrt;
       tiles[15] = Assets.watgrsSE;
       tiles[16] = Assets.watgrsSW;
       tiles[17] = Assets.watgrsNW;
       tiles[18] = Assets.watgrsNE;
   }

}
```

Game class

```
import com.stardust.main.gfx.Assets;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
    public static final int HEIGHT = 512, WIDTH = 512;
    public static boolean running = false;
    public Thread gameThread;
    public Assets assets;
    public TileMapEditor tileMap;
    public static JFrame frame;

    public void init() throws IOException
    {
       tileMap = new TileMapEditor(-WIDTH / 2, -HEIGHT /2);
       assets = new Assets();        
    }

    public synchronized void start()
    {
        if(running)return;          
        running = true;
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop()
    {
        if(!running)return;
        running = false;
        try
        {
            gameThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            init();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double amountOfTicks = 60D;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;

        while(running)
        {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if(delta >= 1)
            {
                update();
                delta--;
            }            
            render();
        }
        stop();
    }

    public void update()
    {

    }

    public void render()
    {


        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null)
        {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        //START RENDER

        tileMap.render(g);

        //END RENDER
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        frame = new JFrame("Tile Engine");
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't code dump. Narrow the scope of the question by removing all the code unrelated to the problem. Tell us what you've tried, and what about it didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry I had no idea what was causing the problem. I understand that  this is vague, but I didn't have the slightest clue.

Comment: A great way to find out more when you have no idea is to either start strategically commenting things until the problem goes away, or you can start with a clean working example and build it up until the problem presents itself again. I know it's hard when getting started, but this site isn't really for "Here's my code, where's the problem" type questions. I encourage you to keep asking questions when you need help, but try to narrow the scope with your own troubleshooting before posting.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is double buffering

I stole this from somewhere just to give you a quick answer:

"Double buffering is conceptually pretty simple, instead of drawing your objects one by one, you draw them on an image and then tell the renderer to draw that entire image. This eliminates the flickering.

Here's an example of how you might do this"

```
class DoubleBufferedCanvas extends Canvas {

    public void update(Graphics g) {
    Graphics offgc;
    Image offscreen = null;
    Dimension d = size();

    // create the offscreen buffer and associated Graphics
    offscreen = createImage(d.width, d.height);
    offgc = offscreen.getGraphics();
    // clear the exposed area
    offgc.setColor(getBackground());
    offgc.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
    offgc.setColor(getForeground());
    // do normal redraw
    paint(offgc);
    // transfer offscreen to window
    g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the content of your answer is from stackoverflow, you can at least link the post you're taking it from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508042/how-do-you-double-buffer-in-java-for-a-game

Comment: I was looking at the post you pulled this from and it's saying if you have implemented a BufferStrategy, which I have, double buffering is already done. So is that correct? Or did I do something wrong with that part?

Comment: right, sorry :D

Comment: So do you know if I did something wrong with the bufferStrategy?

Comment: Never mind, apparently it was a problem to have 3, I changed that to one. The tutorial I had read about creating a small game suggested 3, I don't know why, and I don't know why that worked.